# Create/append element containing blob text which contains quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am try to pass a blob as following:

```
  $("#recordingslist").append('<li><audio src="'+url+'"></audio><a target="_blank" href="'+url+'">'+new Date().toISOString() + '.wav'+'</a><button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="sendWaveToPost('+blob+', '+exercise_id+')">Send Exercise</button></li>');
```

This will not work unfortunately. It will give me an unexpected identifier at the DOCTYPE.

However the following works..

```
  $("#recordingslist").append('<li><audio src="'+url+'"></audio><a target="_blank" href="'+url+'">'+new Date().toISOString() + '.wav'+'</a><button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="sendWaveToPost(\''+blob+'\', '+exercise_id+')">Send Exercise</button></li>');
```

Notice the escape characters around the blob.

Does anyone have an explanation? This makes no sense to me :(

Comment: Just use jQuery to "properly" attach a click handler (and possibly set other attributes). Using the HTML-esque string is fine, but I would *avoid* building non-static data into it.

Comment: Bear in mind that this data is being dynamically generated. I cannot just go $(selector).on('click', function().. unless I use livequery, which is out of the question. 

I am open to suggestions :)

Comment: @zsawaf - I don't think you understand user2864740 nor how to properly create nodes.

Comment: If `blob` comes from external input you are also vulnerable to XSS. What if blob contains `function() { alert(document.cookie); }()`?

Comment: @Paulpro you are very right. But I am not really concerned with security, it is just a small application I am doing for research with kids :)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Unfortunately I am not sure I do understand what user2864740 is trying to say. I am familiar with creating nodes, it will just be a bit tedious, but I will give it a try, and see if it changes anything.

Comment: @zsawaf - If you are properly creating nodes, you can just reference it instead of using a selector. So you don't really need any live query :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, here is how I might do it.. (Actually, I'd just use Knockout, but that's a different story.)

```
// Using a function ensures proper closures of variables and increases
// the self-documentation of code
function createMusicItem (url, blob, exercise_id) {
  var item = $('<li><audio controls></audio><a target="_blank"></a><button class="btn btn-primary">Send Exercise</button></li>');
  item.find("> audio")
      .attr("src", url);
  item.find("> a")
      .attr("href", url)
      .text("" + new Date().toISOString() + '.wav');
  item.find("> button")
      .click(function() {
         // It's so easy to use a normal function/closure; there is no need
         // to worry about any escaping issues because no dynamic data is
         // manually shoved into a string-to-be-parsed.
         sendWaveToPost(blob, exercise_id);
      });
  return item;
}

// And then later, however the values are fetched..
var recordingList = $("#recordingslist");
recordings.forEach(function (r) {
  recordingList.append(createMusicItem(r.url, r.blob, r.exercise_id);
});
```

While this could be built more manually/explicitly, I find this form sufficiently clear *while* it avoids issues like ugly strings and having to worry about "escaping" dynamic data<sup>1</sup>. I've no problem putting static data in the HTML-parsed string, as shown.

[Here is an obligatory jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s4mqz7jk/2/) showing that it works fine with characters like `"` or `'` (and it would be fine with *any* character) within the blob values - simple code, no required escaping, no potential HTML injection. Win.

---

<sup>1</sup> Hand-building HTML strings and mixing structure and dynamic data is a bit like the antiquated practice of not using parameterized queries for SQL; there are better ways to deal with arbitrary data and more interesting problems to explore.

Comment: This is really good. I'm going to search Knockout and see what it's about too. I haven't much experience handling dynamically created objects, I used to just use livequery, but it's so bad... The way you described is very close to what I did, and works perfectly. 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

`blob` must contain something that is not a valid Javascript expression. Consider the case where `blob` contains something like `a a`, then without quotes you have:

```
sendWaveToPost(a a, 0)
```

whereas with quotes you have:

```
sendWaveToPost('a a', 0)
```

You could still end up with errors if blob ever contains a `'` character and you don't escape them. If there is a chance blob could contain a `'` then you should escape it (and also escape `\` characters):

```
sendWaveToPost(\'' + blob.replace(/([\\'])/g, '\\$1') + '\', ...
```

This solves the problem of blobs with `'` or `\` in them, but there are other cases that could go wrong (such as a newline character in the blob) and the escaping would become more complex as you add all the cases. In production code you should always avoid concatenating strings to produce code like this and instead use some sort of templating that automatically escapes for you.

Comment: Wow, how did I not think of that! Thanks! :) 

I was able to solve the problem by creating nodes via javascript as suggested by Derek and user. I'll post my solution in case anyone has the same problem

Comment: @zsawaf That's great! I'm glad you were able to come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to thank everyone for taking the time to help me out.

I was able to solve the problem by creating javascript nodes.

Here is the solution:

```
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  // This does not work, must create nodes manually
  //$("#recordingslist").append('<li><audio src="'+url+'"></audio><a target="_blank" href="'+url+'">'+new Date().toISOString() + '.wav'+'</a><button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="sendWaveToPost(\''+blob+'\', '+exercise_id+')">Send Exercise</button></li>');
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  var au = document.createElement('audio');
  var bt = document.createElement('button');

  au.controls = true;
  au.src = url;
  li.appendChild(au);
  recordingslist.appendChild(li);
  bt.textContent = "Send Exercise";

  bt.onclick =  function(){ sendWaveToPost(blob, exercise_id); }
  li.appendChild(bt);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you wrote `\'' + blob \''`, you entered literal single quotes before and after `blob`. This makes the part of the string you're making look something like this

```
<button onclick="sendWaveToPost('whateverWasIntheBlob', 5)" />
```

instead of like this incorrect version

```
<button onclick="sendWaveToPost(whateverWasIntheBlob, 5)" />
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for you reply. 

I understand that I made the blob a string, I just did it to verify that is the blob passing that is indeed breaking the code.. but what I do not understand is why passing a blob as a parameter is giving me an unexpected identifier.

Comment: What is the type of `blob`? Anything enclosed within those double quotations must be valid JavaScript code; and an unexpected identifier exception means that there is a syntax error lurking around somewhere.

Comment: It was a wav file, @Paulpro kindly explained that there might be ' or \ in blobs, which can be misinterpreted by javascript :) I was able to solve it by creating nodes via javascript